# Trying to create wordpress pagination and breaking while live

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, pagination

I have been coding a pagination for my WordPress site, for a custom post query. and while it works just fine in my local machine it breaks online. I get a 404 when trying to click on page 2, while having posts.

This is what I tried so far:

```
 <?php /*  * Template Name: Archive-posts  */ get_header(); ?>
 
 <main id="primary" class="site-main">
 
     <div class="page-header" id="page-header=news">
         <h1>Archive</h1>
     </div>
 
     <div class="archived">
 
          <div class="archive-grid">
              <!-- Query list of archive posts -->
                 <?php
                 $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                 $args = array(
                     'post_type' => 'archive',
                     'paged' => $paged,
                     'posts_per_page' => 12, // Change this to the number of posts you want to display per page
                     'meta_key' => 'event_date', // Specify the meta key
                     'orderby' => 'meta_value', // Order by the meta value
                     'order' => 'DESC', // Order in descending order
                 );
                 $loop = new WP_Query($args);
                  while ($loop->have_posts()) {
                  $loop->the_post();
                 ?>
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="archive-item">
                     <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                     <?php
                     // Get the event_date custom field value
                     $event_date = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'event_date', true);
                     if ($event_date) {
                         // Convert the date to a more readable format
                         $formatted_date = date('F j, Y', strtotime($event_date));
                         echo '<div class="event-date">' . esc_html($formatted_date) . '</div>';
                     }
                     ?>
                 </a>
                 <?php
                  }
                  ?>
         </div>
         
         <div class="pagination-news">
             <?php
             $pagination_args = array(
                 'prev_text' => __('Previous page', 'mothertongues'),
                 'next_text' => __('Next page', 'mothertongues'),
                 'mid_size' => 2,
                 'total' => $loop->max_num_pages,
                 'current' => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                 'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                 'format' => '?paged=%#%',
             );
     
             echo paginate_links($pagination_args);
             ?>
         </div>
     
     </div> </main>
 
 <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // Reset the post data get_footer(); ?>
```

any help would be great.

Comment: I tried to consult the question listed and make modifications in the query but it is still not working for me, any other leads?